# How to add values from coinmarketcap API to telegram message?

Tags: node.js, api, telegram-bot, price

I'm trying to finish telegram bot that will after several commands respond with message... Lost any hope of trying that i can solve this alone. Those commands with predefined message are done and working like a charm.. But now im stucked on the /price command which should show coin value in the message from coinmarket API respond..

I tried many variants but following results always called for API Call error: or message like [object Object]..

```
     ALQO: $0.0443407142 | 9.73% 
     ETH: 0.000313592 | 10.14% 
     BTC: 0.0000107949 | 9.5% 
     Cap: $2,545,718
```

This text above is correct respond from bot... Unfortunately with free API from CMC i can do only price with USD so correct answer should be

```
       Coinname: Price | Change%
       Cap: Marketcap
```

My code of /price command

```
    //This is /price command code
    'use strict';

     const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');

     const rp = require('request-promise');
     const requestOptions = {
     method: 'GET',
     uri: 'https://pro- 
     api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest? 
     id=3501&convert=USD',
     headers: {
     'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MYFREEAPIKEYFROMCMC'
      },
      json: true,
      gzip: true
     };

     rp(requestOptions).then(response => {
     console.log('API call response:', response['data'][3501]);
     }).catch((err) => {
     console.log('API call error:', err.message);
   });

    class PriceController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
    PriceHandler($) {
    rp(requestOptions).then(response => {
    console.log('API call response:', response['data'][3501]);
    $.sendMessage('Cryptosoul: price', response['data']['USD']['price'] 
    [3501]);
   }).catch((err) => {
    $.sendMessage('API call error:', err.message);
  });
 }

get routes() {
    return {
        'priceCommand': 'PriceHandler'
    };
  };
}

 module.exports = PriceController;
```

Respond from API after node index.js (turning bot on, (message from visual studio terminal)

```
     API call response: { id: 3501,
     name: 'CryptoSoul',
     symbol: 'SOUL',
     slug: 'cryptosoul',
     circulating_supply: 143362580.31,
     total_supply: 499280500,
     max_supply: null,
     date_added: '2018-10-25T00:00:00.000Z',
     num_market_pairs: 3,
     tags: [],
     platform:
   { id: 1027,
     name: 'Ethereum',
     symbol: 'ETH',
     slug: 'ethereum',
     token_address: '0xbb1f24c0c1554b9990222f036b0aad6ee4caec29' },
     cmc_rank: 1194,
     last_updated: '2019-04-01T23:03:07.000Z',
   quote:
    { USD:
     { price: 0.000188038816143,
     volume_24h: 11691.5261174775,
     percent_change_1h: 0.29247,
     percent_change_24h: 0.0222015,
     percent_change_7d: 4.69888,
     market_cap: 26957.72988069816,
     last_updated: '2019-04-01T23:03:07.000Z' } } }
```

The messages that appears after /price command triggered
"API call error:"
"[object Object]"
"Error while running node index.js (bad code)"[Chat with Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JBQo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could see, you are incorrectly accessing the resulting json response object here:

```
$.sendMessage('Cryptosoul: price', response['data']['USD']['price'] 
[3501])
```

Just pretty printing that response object gives a correct way to access certain properties.

```
{
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2019-04-02T08:38:09.230Z",
        "error_code": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "elapsed": 14,
        "credit_count": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "3501": {
            "id": 3501,
            "name": "CryptoSoul",
            "symbol": "SOUL",
            "slug": "cryptosoul",
            "circulating_supply": 143362580.31,
            "total_supply": 499280500,
            "max_supply": null,
            "date_added": "2018-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
            "num_market_pairs": 3,
            "tags": [],
            "platform": {
                "id": 1027,
                "name": "Ethereum",
                "symbol": "ETH",
                "slug": "ethereum",
                "token_address": "0xbb1f24c0c1554b9990222f036b0aad6ee4caec29"
            },
            "cmc_rank": 1232,
            "last_updated": "2019-04-02T08:37:08.000Z",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 0.000201447607597,
                    "volume_24h": 12118.3983544441,
                    "percent_change_1h": 1.48854,
                    "percent_change_24h": 6.88076,
                    "percent_change_7d": 12.4484,
                    "market_cap": 28880.04882238228,
                    "last_updated": "2019-04-02T08:37:08.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So we could see that `price` field is located under `USD` object wich itself located under `quote` object, which is missing in your code.

Proper way to get it would be:

```
const price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];
```

PriceHandler code:

```
PriceHandler($) {
    rp(requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            const price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];
            $.sendMessage("Cryptosoul: price", price);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("API call error:", err.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: After adding: const price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];             
             C:\Users\Adminstrator\dev\my-bot\controllers\price.js:22
              price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];
              ^

             ReferenceError: response is not defined
I tried add above this code 
const response = 'Api call response:';
const price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];
Error
Response:
C:\Users\Administrator\dev\my-bot\controllers\price.js:23
const price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];

Comment: You have to put it right before that line `$.sendMessage('Cryptosoul: price', response['data']['USD']['price'][3501]);` which was in your previous code snippet

Comment: Thanks for answer.. I tried to put right before the message line but its still same as it says: `const price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];
              ^

ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Comment: Try this code snippet for PriceGandler
`PriceHandler($) {
        rp(requestOptions)
            .then((response) => {
                const price = response["data"][3501]["quote"]["USD"]["price"];
                $.sendMessage("Cryptosoul: price", price);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("API call error:", err.message);
            });
    }`